# Unicode escape in C

Tags: unicode, escaping

I m using CURL to retreive a JSON string from Wikipedia, eg

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=1&format=json&search=syntax

I don't use a JSON parser, and I am searching a way to remove the unicode part, which is useless for me.

I have already tried `&utf8=` in url, and WideCharToMultiByte and wcstombs.

I just want to convert this string to ANSI format, to be used in another application, even if I will lose data.

Here is the code I am using to convert the string:

```
void UnicodeToAnsi(char *str, char *str2)
{
    unsigned char ch;

    char *pr = str;
    char *pw = str2;

    while ( (*pr) != 0 )
    {
        ch = (*pr);
        if ( ch == '\\' )
        {
            if ( *(pr+1) == 'u')
            {

                char szANSIString [2] = {'\0'};
                wchar_t wcsString[2] = {0,'\0'};

                char h[5]={'\0'};
                int v;
                strncpy(h,pr + 2,4);


                v = (int)strtol(h, NULL, 16);
#if 0
                wcsString[0] = v;

#ifndef _WIN32
                WideCharToMultiByte ( CP_ACP, // ANSI code page
                WC_COMPOSITECHECK,     // Check for accented characters
                wcsString,         // Source Unicode string
                -1,                    // -1 means string is zero-terminated
                szANSIString,          // Destination char string
                sizeof(szANSIString),  // Size of buffer
                NULL,                  // No default character
                NULL );                // Don't care about this flag
#else
                wcstombs(szANSIString, wcsString, sizeof(szANSIString));
#endif
                ch = *szANSIString;
                if (ch == '\0') ch = '?';
#endif

                //bored with this unicode, easy way

                ch = '-';
                if (v == 232) ch = 138;
                if (v == 233) ch = 130;
                if (v == 234) ch = 136;
                if (v == 224) ch = 133;
                if (v == 225) ch = 'a';
                if (v == 226) ch = 'a';
                if (v == 257) ch = 'a';
                if (v == 231) ch = 135;


                pr = pr + 5;
            }

        }
        (*pw) = ch;

        ++pw;
        ++pr;
    }

    *pw = '\0';

    return;

}
```

Comment: The JSON from that URL is in ASCII/UTF8 (even without adding `&utf=` to the URL) so just parse it as-is. The only Unicode present is the encoded `\u02c8s\u026an\u02cct\u00e6ks` sequence (`ˈsɪnˌtæks`) inside the JSON data. If you want that in ANSI, parse it out and decode each `\uXXXX` to a UTF16 codeunit (in UTF16, the sequence represents codepoints `U+02C8` `U+0073` `U+026A` `U+006E` `U+02CC` `U+0074` `U+00E6` `U+006B` `U+0073`). Any decent JSON parser will parse/decode to a wide string for you, which you can then convert to ANSI using either of the functions you mentioned...

Comment: ... If you are having trouble doing this, then please show the actual code you are using.

Comment: I have tried to use that [link](http://pastebin.com/v0DKjjTh) you can see in the code, the good method that work on windows but not on linux, and the easy way I have used to work on both.

Comment: that code is trying to convert each individual `\uXXXX` as-is. That is not the correct approach, as it does not account for UTF16 surrogates. And the code does not account for differences in how `wchar_t` is encoded on different platforms (UTF16 on Windows, UTF32 on other platforms). In JSON, each `\uXXXX` represents a UTF16 codeunit, so they have to be decoded as UTF16 properly on all platforms. The code you showed is a good start, but it is incomplete.

Comment: Allocate an array of 16bit values (uint16, etc) that is `strlen(str)+1` in length, then copy each `char` from `str` into it, decoding each `\uXXXX` into a 16bit value (`strtol()`) as you go along, and then null-terminate the array. After copying the entire `str` data, convert the entire array from UTF16 to ANSI in one go. Use something like ICONV or ICU on non-Windows platforms.